# Minicom doesn't work

Tags: cisco, minicom

I installed minicom and configured it with a usb to serial adapter. When I run minicom with sudo minicom I see only this message :
Welcome to minicom 2.7

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Jan  1 2014, 17:13:19.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0, 10:07:54

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

I should see a Cisco ios. What I can do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be you can try to use **picocom** like this:

```
sudo picocom -b 115200 -r -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

with no port reset (-r) and no port locking (-l). Also special keys you can see in the man picocom

Comment: I tried with picocom but i see this and nothing more :

daniele@daniele-XPS-13-9343:~$ sudo picocom -b 115200 -r -l /dev/ttyUSB0
picocom v1.7

port is        : /dev/ttyUSB0
flowcontrol    : none
baudrate is    : 115200
parity is      : none
databits are   : 8
escape is      : C-a
local echo is  : no
noinit is      : no
noreset is     : yes
nolock is      : yes
send_cmd is    : sz -vv
receive_cmd is : rz -vv
imap is        : 
omap is        : 
emap is        : crcrlf,delbs,

Terminal ready

Comment: Same issue with me

Answer (score 6):

It seems you cannot input anything on minicom, if that is the case then go in Minicom configuration by:

minicom -o -s

and select the serial port setup option, then turn off the Hardware flow control. I also had software flow control to OFF. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved. 
If I use picocom with your command doesn't work because the bitrate 115200 is wrong. If I launch picocom with

```
sudo picocom -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

it works fine.

therefore if I change the bitrate in minicom also. It work fine.

finally I relsoved. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You should just press enter. When you start minicom, the login prompt was already issued on terminal and is not displayed again.
If nothing helps make sure you have proper flow settings (in port configuration). For emulation connections like via USB or Ethernet you usually should have both off. Check speed too.

Comment: ook I setup the port as ttyUSB0. About speed . What I can do ? you have any values that I can use ?

Comment: Speed must exactly match the one that is set on the receiving end. Otherwise you will see only eldritch runes or nothing at all.